# How to alter the Views UI config form

Tags: views

Part 1: How do I add a form element (ie checkbox) to the field of a specific type (ie all image fields) inside the admin Views UI.  What code do I need include in a custom module.

Part 2: How do I save it to the database.

[image]

This is not a default view.
I am not creating a need field.  I am trying to alter an existing field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to solve this problem with 2 functions:

- `hook_field_formatter_info_alter()`
- `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` where FORM_ID = views_ui_config_item_form

`hook_field_formatter_info_alter()` lets you set the default value.

The value itself gets save to the view/database.  There is no extra code you need to write for this to happen.

Below is an example that went into MYMODULE.module file (MYMODULE = image_field_caption).

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_info_alter().
 */
function image_field_caption_field_formatter_info_alter(&$info) {
  // Add a caption visible setting to image field.
  $info['image']['settings'] += array(
    'caption_visible' => TRUE,
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 *
 * Altering formatter settings for field handlers in Views.
 * TODO: Drupal 8 change to hook_field_formatter_settings_form_alter().
 */
function image_field_caption_form_views_ui_config_item_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Get the views handler.
  $handler = $form_state['handler'];

  // Check to see if the field is an image type.
  if (isset($handler->field_info['type']) && $handler->field_info['type'] == 'image') {
    $form['options']['settings']['caption_visible'] = array(
      '#title' => t('Include Caption'),
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#default_value' => $handler->instance['display']['_custom']['settings']['caption_visible'],
      '#description' => t('By default, the caption is attached to the image in the view.'),
    );
  }
}
```

Another alternative for Drupal 7 is to use the [Field Formatter Settings](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_formatter_settings) API module.  This module add the `hook_field_formatter_settings_form_alter()` hook which you can use.

For Drupal 8 `hook_field_formatter_settings_form_alter()` is now part of core see [field_ui.api.php API documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field_ui%21field_ui.api.php/8).

Comment: At the time of this answer, the function has not been added to the api.drupal.org Drupal 8 section.  An alternative link is http://api.hostdog.gr/api/drupal-8/drupal!core!modules!field_ui!field_ui.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_settings_form_alter/8.x

Comment: How can I get `$handler = $form_state['handler'];` in d8 ?

Comment: Posted d8 solution in the new answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Views handlers https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_handlers/7.

Basically, you need to extend the handler class that is used by that field which in your case is field_image.

In order to start and make your custom handler work you need two basic functions to tell Views you mean some business with them. These are  hook_views_api() and hook_views_data_alter() function.

MODULE.module

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_api().
 */
function uc_addons_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => 3,
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'uc_addons') . '/views',
  );
}
```

MODULE.views.inc

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data_alter().
 */
function uc_addons_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  dsm($data);
}
```

The hook_views_data_alter() function needs to be inside your MODULE.views.inc file.

Lastly of course is your handler w/c adds your field by extending the base handler as you can get more idea from the link. Also from my experience, the saving of values from fields are taken care by Views already.

Comment: I am changing all fields of a specific type.  If possible i do not want to create a custom handler.   I want to change alter all image type fields, that way other modules can alter image type fields as well.

Comment: Absolutely, you still need the handler for the custom field's functionality then inside hook_views_data_alter() you would place your code to run through the $data array, find the handler you extended and update the value to use your handler.

Answer (score 1):

**Drupal 8** example: how to add a new custom setting in the Views UI config form.

This example adds new option to the Ajax settings by checking the `use_ajax` option, but you can change it to anything you like.

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_views_ui_edit_display_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if (!empty($form['options']['use_ajax'])) {
    /** @var \Drupal\views\Entity\View $view */
    $view = $form_state->getStorage()['view'];
    $display = $view->getExecutable()->getDisplay();
    $form['options']['mymodule_option'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => t('Use mymodule_option'),
      '#default_value' => !empty($display->display['display_options']['mymodule_option']),
    ];

    array_unshift($form['actions']['submit']['#submit'], '_MYMODULE_form_views_ui_edit_display_submit');
  }
}

/**
 * Form submit callback for views_ui_edit_display.
 */
function _MYMODULE_form_views_ui_edit_display_submit(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  /** @var \Drupal\views\Entity\View $view */
  $view = $form_state->getStorage()['view'];
  $display = $view->getExecutable()->getDisplay();
  $display->display['display_options']['mymodule_option'] = $form_state->getValue('mymodule_option');
}
```